# Retrieving information from sheet based on cell reference?

Tags: excel

I am creating a dashboard for team performance say monthly sales.In excel, Every member has a tab in a yearly sheet where they enter their sales values for each month in a column and there's a total at the top of the column. Each month has its own column on that sheet. I am trying to consolidate the data on one dashboard sheet and have the members names(tab names) as row titles and the months as column titles and then have each persons monthly sales fill in the appropriate cell.

Does anyone have any ideas on what formulas I could use in excel to do this. I have thought about defining as a name but I am unfamiliar with this tool.

Comment: Maybe INDIRECT but it's volatile so should be used sparingly.

Comment: I would create query and merge all of the sheets together and transform those month columns so there's only 1 column for month. Then I would use vlookups or sumifs to summarize the data

Comment: You might also be able to [consolidate the worksheets into a single PivotTable](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-pivottable-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5)

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a mock up of your data & what you've tried please.